# CoordinatorLayout returns null

Tags: android

I am unable to get value of `CoordinatorLayout` in my `Activity`. When i try to get value by `findviewbyid()` it return null.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/login_bg">


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java:

```
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayoutLogin);
    }
```

I am unable to understand why it is not working. Help me out.

I am using Samsung Note 8 with Android 9(One UI) installed also tried it on Samsung S8 and the behavior is same.

Comment: You just forgot to do **`setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);`**

Comment: Can you please confirm if your findViewById call is after `setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_xml);`

I just don't see it in the snippet that you have provided here

Comment: @NileshRathod, k1slay  thanks
this is the problem i am trying to get get id before setting layout.

Comment: I am wondering too .. How will `private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout` as local variable will compile ?

Comment: Oops error in copying @ADM